# Simplify sympy.KroneckerDelta

Tags: sympy

Is there a way to "simplify" a `sympy.KroneckerDelta`? For example,

```
i, j = sympy.symbols('i j')
sympy.KroneckerDelta((i+1)/2, (j+1)/2)
```

could also be expressed more simply as

```
sympy.KroneckerDelta(i, j)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an internal function [`_simplify_delta`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/f1847a857dbb3cc902a0ffb3b85e139a3fc9f656/sympy/concrete/delta.py#L148) that does this.

```
import sympy
from sympy.concrete.delta import _simplify_delta
i, j = sympy.symbols('i j')
expr = sympy.KroneckerDelta((i+1)/2, (j+1)/2)
print(_simplify_delta(expr))
```

prints `KroneckerDelta(i, j)`. Remarks:

1. `_simplify_delta` only works on a single instance of `KroneckerDelta`, not on expressions involving deltas.
2. It is not used by `simplify`: the generic `simplify` does not know much, if anything, about special properties of Kronecker delta.